# Search for "hidden Data" in FilteredTree

Tags: java, eclipse, filter, tree

How can i search for "hidden"-Data in the Filtered-TreeView. Till now I can just search for the TreeItem's names and Filter them. Now I want to search for data stored in my TreeObjects.
Where should I attache the String I want to search for ?

I try to become more detailed:

I've a :

```
    class TreeObject implements IAdaptable {
    protected String name;
    protected String Data;
    private TreeParent parent; ....
```

Now I want to search for it's

```
    protected String Data;
```

how can i get access to:
 -The **TreeObject**
 -The texfield's text of the Filtered Tree View

Here you see a Picture of the Methodes which can be Overwritten:
[image: No SELECT Functiobn here]

This is what I get wehn i use another Filter-Type:

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: You don't need access to the textfield. You just have to tell the FilteredTree how it should compare the text against your objects. See my answer.

Comment: I cant Override the methode because it's final, eclipse says.

Comment: oh well, then use the `ViewerFilter`.

Comment: But ViewerFilter can't be used in FilteredTree.

Comment: Because only Pattern-Filter is supported, I think.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30686/discussion-between-schwenk-and-user714965)

Answer (score 1):

You have to overwrite the `select` method of the [`ViewerFilter`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/PatternFilter.html) which you are setting in the `FilteredTree`. From the Javadoc of `select`:

> Returns whether the given element makes it through this filter.

So in your implementation you can check the fields of your object and decide if it should be filtered out or not.

Example (don't know if this compiles)

```
    TreeViewer viewer = filteredTree.getViewer();
    viewer.addFilter(new ViewerFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element) {
            if (element instanceof TreeObject && filterString != null && !filterString.isEmpty()) {
                TreeObject obj = (TreeObject) element;
                String data = obj.getData().toLowerCase(); // Your Data field!
                return data.startsWith(filterString.toLowerCase());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: But the "PatternFilter filter = new PatternFilter();" has no select -Function to OVerride.

Comment: @schwenk it has: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/PatternFilter.html#select(org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: @schwenk In `TreeViewer` it is abstract. Use this class as mentioned in my answer.